# Xamarin Forms: How to reset device timer in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Hi I am building an app using Xamarin Forms PCL project. My app will run on android, ios, windows 10 and windows 8.1.
I have created a function which will start a timer of 10 minutes which will trigger a function. However on some button click event I want to reset this timer.

Here is my code:-

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), () =>
{
    MyFunction();
});
```

I tried this- but it didn't worked as I expected -

```
// run task in 10 minutes
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), () =>
{
    if (needsToRecur)
    {
        // returning true will fire task again in 10 minutes.
        return true;
    }

    // No longer need to recur. Stops firing task
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Device.StartTimer doesn't really have a reset mechanism.  Try https://github.com/ufuf/AdvancedTimer instead

Comment: @Jason It supports cross-platform?

Comment: yes, it was explicitly written for Xamarin Forms